# Getting specific date/time values in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have a cron task that logs a value in my database every 15 minutes so my database rows look something like this:

```
1, 100, 1311312600
1, 100, 1311313200
1, 90, 1311313800
```

etc.

The third field is a time() value.

Lets say the current time is 1:00PM on 07/22/2011. I want to see all of yesterdays values, so I need the following times for my SQL query.

```
07/22/2011 00:00:00
07/21/2011 00:00:00
```

How do I generate those values from the current time? Keep getting tripped up!

Comment: What RDBMS is this? MS SQL Server? Looks like it from the date format..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$yesterday_begin = strtotime('-1 day 12:00:00 AM');
$yesterday_end   = strtotime('-1 day 11:59:59 PM');
```

Then

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN $yesterday_begin AND $yesterday_end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from logtable
where DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestampfield)) = '2011/07/21'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$start = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n') - 1, $day, date('Y');
$end = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), $day, date('Y');
```